# Why is my WiFi speed killed by certain events?

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, apple-silicon

> **Update:** This is a bug that has been recently fixed with the release of macOS Ventura 13.1.

I have a MacBook Pro M1 14" and have it connected to a 5Ghz WiFi.

I can usually use WiFi and Bluetooth together (i.e. I have AirPods Pro and a mouse connected). Certain events, though, will slow down the Wifi speeds to a crawl and it will often only go back to normal after a reboot:

- waking up an another nearby device like an iPhone or an iPad (not the watch)
- any notification (even if hidden by DND focus)
- (re-)connecting a bluetooth device, i.e. temporarily taking out one AirPod and putting it back in.

The problem is most apparent when playing games over streaming services like GeforceNow. They become immediately unusable.

I have found a temporary fix which I will add as an answer, but I am very much open to better solutions.

Comment: Instead of putting the resolution in the question, please add it as an answer  and select it as the accepted solution

Comment: @Allan I already did. The accepted solution is the one with the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also see *"Recent Apple updates leading to WiFi issues & an interim solution"*:
https://www.meter.com/mac-osx-awdl-psa

and

https://systemstatus.ucla.edu/status?id=status_record&service=a8226ec01b1651509ca4a602b24bcb20

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away, when I disabled the virtual network interface for the Apple Wireless Direct Link protocol in the terminal:

```
sudo ifconfig awdl0 down
```

After I'm done with my gaming session, I re-enable the interface with

```
sudo ifconfig awdl0 up
```

People seem to have had issues with AWDL for some time. The most recent I could find was [this comment](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/slow-wi-fi-on-macbook-pro-14-when-bluetooth-is-on.2331996/post-30890845) in the Macrumors forum.